# Selective extraction of data from external site using DOM PHP web crawler

Tags: php, web-crawler, simple-html-dom

I have this PHP dom web crawler which works fine. it extracts mentioned tag along with its link from a (external) forum site to my page.

But recently i ran into a problem. Like

this is the HTML of the forum data::

```
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td width="1%" height="25">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="64%" height="25" class="FootNotes2"><a href="/files/forum/2017/1/837880.php" target="_top" class="Links2">Hispanic Study Partner</a> - dreamer1984</td>
    <td width="1%" height="25">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="14%" height="25" class="FootNotes2" align="center">02/28/17 01:42</td>
    <td width="1%" height="25">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="8%" height="25" align="Center" class="FootNotes2">0</td>
    <td width="1%" height="25">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="9%" height="25" align="Center" class="FootNotes2">200</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="1%" height="25">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="64%" height="25" class="FootNotes2"><a href="/files/forum/2017/1/837879.php" target="_top" class="Links2">nbme</a> - monariyadh</td>
    <td width="1%" height="25">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="14%" height="25" class="FootNotes2" align="center">02/27/17 23:12</td>
    <td width="1%" height="25">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="8%" height="25" align="Center" class="FootNotes2">0</td>
    <td width="1%" height="25">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="9%" height="25" align="Center" class="FootNotes2">108</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Now if we consider the above code (table data) as the only statements available in that site. and if i tried to extract it with a web crawler like,

```
<?php
    require_once('dom/simple_html_dom.php'); 
    $html = file_get_html('http://www.sitename.com/');
    foreach($html->find('td.FootNotes2') as $element) {
    echo $element;
}
?>
```

It extracts al the data that is inside with a class name as "FootNote2"

Now what if i want to extract specific data in tag, for example names like, " dreamer1984" and "monariyadh" from the first tag/line.

and what if i wanted to extract data from 3rd (skipping the rest) which has same class names.

Please note that i can use "regex" like

```
preg_match_all('/<td.+?FootNotes2.+?<a.+?<\/a> - (?P<name>.*?)<\/td>.+?<td.+?FootNotes2.+?(?P<date>\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2})/siu', $subject, $matchs);

foreach ($matchs['name'] as $k => $v){
    var_dump('name: '. $v, 'relative date: '. $matchs['date'][$k]);
}
```

But i prefer to find solution for this in DOM parser...
Any help is appreciated..

Comment: Some sort of text parsing will be necessary (e.g. via regex) I don't think you can avoid that. The best you can do is limit the regex bit to the text content of the td element.

Comment: @harishk check my answer is that what you want?

Answer (score 2):

As I said in my comment some text processing is unavoidable, however you can get the text element associated with the td like so :

```
require_once('dom/simple_html_dom.php'); 
$html = file_get_html('http://www.sitename.com/');
foreach ($html->find("tr") as $row) {
        $element = $row->find('td.FootNotes2',0);
        if ($element == null) { continue; }
        $textNode = array_filter($element->nodes, function ($n) {
            return $n->nodetype == 3;        //Text node type, like in jQuery     
        });

        if (!empty($textNode)) {
            $text = current($textNode);
            echo $text;         
        }

    }
```

This echoes:

```
- dreamer1984
- monariyadh
```

Do with that what you will.

Updated to only find the first td for each tr.

Comment: Ok, but how to avoid the last two things like, the numbers , as "0, 200 ,and 0, 108"..... and what if i want to echo the name (dreamer1984) and the date on different places...?

Comment: @harishk Updated. Now it finds the rows and the first `td.Footnotes2` of each row. If you also want the 3rd element then do  `find(...,2)` as well.

Comment: Dude, it prints the exact but gives out two errors repeatedly like, `Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given ` and `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object ` for `$textNode = array_filter($element->nodes, function ($n) {` line...

Comment: @harishk you could just check if `$element` is not null

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136942/discussion-between-harishk-and-apokryfos).

Comment: dude, it works fine,....but i just tried to add a while loop to pull data from multiple pages,,, like
`$i = 1; 
while(true){ 
//code 
} 
$i++;`
`but it came error as , Warning: file_get_contents(1): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`
and
`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function find() on boolean`
what does it mean dude

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract only text (not tags and its contain)

```
foreach ($html->find("td.FootNotes2") as $element) {

    $children = $element->children; // get an array of children
    foreach ($children AS $child) {
      $child->outertext = ''; // This removes the element, but MAY NOT remove it from the original $myDiv
    }
    echo $element->innertext."<br>";
}
```

o/p:

```
- dreamer1984
02/28/17 01:42
0
200
- monariyadh
02/27/17 23:12
0
108
```

Comment: yes, actually but i needed only the first two columns,,,,

Comment: and indeed, the other guys answer gave the solution to me but except when i use a while loop it gave errors... please come over to  the discussion room to check it out...http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136942/discussion-between-harishk-and-apokryfos

Comment: you there dude?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use regex either way so no sense overcomplicating it:

```
foreach($html->find('tr') as $tr) {
  echo preg_replace('/.* - /', '', $tr->find('td',1)->text()) . "\n";
  echo $tr->find('td',3)->text() . "\n";
}
```

I really don't like apokryfos' approach to this, it's a lot of confusion with no benefit.